# reading data from python file into javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, react-native

Hi I have been trying to create an application using reactJS which takes a file (.mf4 format ) as input, reads data and plots it. But there does not exist any JS librarie for reading data from .mf4 file, however there are python libraries.

Lets say `getdata()` is a python function which returns say python dataframe.

How can I call `getdata()` function in JS and get data?

what are the different ways I can implement this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This is not a code writing service, and you're more likely to get help if you share what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Export from python to JSON format and read the JSON with React JS Hooks:

https://blog.nubecolectiva.com/como-mostrar-datos-mediante-hooks-con-react-js-16-12/

In you front you can use Chart JS or other library.